# Issue with Queue Bot Discord configuration

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, discord, discord.js

I'm installing a Discord Bot and I'm stuck at the build stage...

Here is the link of the github : https://github.com/ArrowM/Queue-Bot

I opened a GCP Instance and also installed Postgresql.

I have modified my config.json (and only that) and when I launch the"npm run build, I receive:

```
"queue-bot@1.0.0 build
tsc -p .
src/utilities/VoiceUtils.ts:33:66 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'import("/home/max/queuebot/node_modules/discord-api-types/payloads/v9/voice").GatewayVoiceState' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/home/max/queuebot/node_modules/@
discordjs/builders/node_modules/discord-api-types/payloads/v9/voice").GatewayVoiceState'.
The types of 'member.user.flags' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'import("/home/max/queuebot/node_modules/discord-api-types/payloads/v9/user").UserFlags' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/max/queuebot/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/node_modules/discord-api-types/payloads/v9/user").UserFlags
33 Voice.adapters.get(payload.guild_id)?.onVoiceStateUpdate(payload);
~~~
Found 1 error"
```

I still try to run the following command (npm start) and then I get this:

```
queue-bot@1.0.0 start
cd build && node bot.js
node:internal/process/promises:246
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.132.0.2:5432
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1146:16) {
errno: -111,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: 'xxxxxx',
port: 5432
}"
```

I'm starting to get stuck on this issue so if you can help me that would be great

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Is Postgres running on the same machine as your bot? Have you double-checked the database IP and port?